# What optimizations are possible when loop variable is undefined on overflow?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow

[This article](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) features an example snippet of C code which the compiler can optimize thanks to the fact that overflow is undefined for the type of the loop counter.

Here's the snippet with the comment

> ```c
> for (i = 0; i <= N; ++i) { ... }
> ```
>
> In this loop, the compiler can assume that the loop will iterate exactly N+1 times if "i" is undefined on overflow, which allows a broad range of loop optimizations to kick in. On the other hand, if the variable is defined to wrap around on overflow, then the compiler must assume that the loop is possibly infinite (which happens if N is INT_MAX) - which then disables these important loop optimizations. This particularly affects 64-bit platforms since so much code uses "int" as induction variables.

I have quite a few doubts:

- I understand that, if the type of `i` is undefined on overflow, the compiler can assume that `i` will not wrap around, but why would this imply that the loop runs `N+1` times? Can't it be that `i` is altered in the body of the loop?
- Even given that assumption, what optimization could it do based on that? If `N` is not known at compile-time, for instance, the loop can't be unrolled, can it?
- "Broad range of loop optimizations" makes me think I'm missing a lot, here.

Comment: `int res = 0; for (int i = a; i < a + N; ++i) ++res;` can be converted to `int res = N > 0 ? N : 0;`

Comment: Indeed content of the loop should be taken into account, break or modifying `i` might change loop count.

Comment: another one `int res = 0; for (int i = a; i < a + N; ++i) res+= f(i); for (int i = a; i < a + N; ++i) res += f(i);` can become `int res = 0; for (int i = a; i < a + N; ++i) { res += f(i); } res *= 2;`

Comment: @Jarod42, aren't those examples worth an answer? :D

Comment: @Enlico "Can't it be that i is altered in the body of the loop?" --> Yes, yet for the purpose of illustrative code, `i` is assumed to not change in the loop body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can't it be that i is altered in the body of the loop?

No, they mean this:

```
size_t N = getSize();
for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) { 
   // i never changed here
}
```

Assuming a 64-bit platform, `N` might be too big for the loop to run correctly. (Perhaps the programmer knows that `N` is never too big, but the compiler doesn't). But if `N` is too big, `i` will overflow, and overflow "cannot" happen. So the compiler can assume that `N` is never too big after all -- even if it sometimes is.

By contrast,

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
```

here, even if `N` is the maximum representable `unsigned`, `i` won't overflow, but rather wrap around, which is completely legal. The compiler no longer can assume that `N` is never too big, and must deal with a loop that potentially doesn't end.

> what optimization could it do based on that?

[Just watch this in awe](https://godbolt.org/z/Tbce1v34v).

If the compiler know the loop is going to end, it is able to use a (presumably) more efficient set of instructions. The machine code becomes much longer and much more complicated, but who cares if it wins us 3.27 picoseconds per run?

Comment: In order to _awe_, I'd need to read assembly, though :( Is it the case that at the section labelled `.LBB0_7` is summing 8 elements and then loops (based on what conditoin, I can't tell)?

Comment: @Enlico It looks like so. Based on whether there are still 8 or more elements to sum up, which is a condition kept in rax (as far as I can understand).

Comment: @Enlico: It's unrolled with each iteration doing 8 *vectors* of 16 bytes each, so 8x 4 = 32 elements.  That's why it's doing `add     rdx, 32`.  (It uses RDX with a scale factor in the addressing modes, so that's 32 elements, not 32 bytes).  Use `-fno-unroll-loops` to simplify the asm so the inner loop just does one 16-byte vector per iteration (or 32B AVX2 with `-march=x86-64-v3`). https://godbolt.org/z/b4Grd3M1z  It still needs to horizontal-sum after that loop, hence the shuffles, and still needs to do the last `N%4 = 0..3` leftover elements, hence the scalar loop at the very bottom.

Answer (score 6):

> I understand that, if the type of `i` is undefined on overflow, the compiler can assume that `i` will not wrap around, but why would this imply that the loop runs `N+1` times? Can't it be that `i` is altered in the body of the loop?

Answering the second question first, the author is taking it, for their example, that `i` is not altered in the loop and that the loop does not contain a `break` or other code that would terminate the loop. It is merely a briefly presented example aimed at a knowledgeable audience that is expected to be familiar with these things and to fill in the gaps.

Answering the first question, the fact that `i` will not wrap does not imply the loop will run `N+1` times. The passage does not say that, it says it **allows** the compiler to **assume** that. The reasoning is this:

- If `N` is such that `++i` never overflows, the loop runs exactly `N+1` times.
- If `N` is such that `++i` overflows at some point, the behavior is not defined, and the language standard allows any behavior. If the program crashes, that conforms to the standard. If `N+1` wraps and the test `i <= N` is always true, and the loop iterates forever, that conforms to the standard. If the loop runs `N+1` times, that conforms to the standard. As the compiler implementor, we can choose any of these behaviors, and the resulting behavior will conform to the language standard.

Given a free choice, in this instance we choose to behave as if the loop always runs `N+1` times because this is a simplifying assumption: It gives us the same specification for both the non-overflow case and the overflow case.

> - Even given that assumption, what optimization could it do based on that? If `N` is not known at compile-time, for instance, the loop can't be unrolled, can it?

If the loop is `for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) { sum += i; }`, we can optimize to `sum += N*(N+1)/2;` (calulated with appropriate regard for possible overflow) and remove the loop entirely. If we were required to behave as if `i` wrapped upon overflow, we could not remove the loop entirely; we would need a test to see if the value of `N` were such that the loop exited or continued forever. (Other language in the standard about loops making progress notwithstanding; this is a simplified example.)

> - "Broad range of loop optimizations" makes me think I'm missing a lot, here.

It is a broad claim to make without listing several, so do not worry about that part too much.

Comment: I can fill the gaps. But from my point of view (I guess my C++ mentality conditions my views), if there's no complex looping logic, in the sense that `i` is not altered in the loop, nor are there `continue` and `break` and the likes, then I'd question why is one using a loop at all rather than using `std::for_each`, or other iterator- or range-based algorithms. This made me think that maybe the matter was more complicated than it looked. Apparently it's just that simple. I guess I should have taken into more account that article is for "every C programmer", not for "every C++ programmer".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of code that can be optimized under this assumption, and this version is even simpler because we're using `<` rather than `<=`:

```cpp
int Foo(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Obviously the normal way to interpret this code would be to omit the loop entirely, and just rewrite it as:

```cpp
int Foo(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
  return vec.size();
}
```

If `vec.size() <= INT_MAX` then everything is normal and there's nothing tricky to think about. But what if `vec.size() > INT_MAX`? Is the simplified/rewritten version still valid? This is actually important to consider because on most sane 64-bit implementations `vec.size()` will return a `size_t` which is a 64-bit unsigned integer.

In the huge-vector case there is a problem after `INT_MAX` iterations because if `i` underflows then the behavior is undefined, and this means that we could get things like an infinite loop, meaning our simplified rewritten version is not valid. However, since underflow is UB this means that the compiler can assume this won't happen, and it is permitted to make the simplification we made above.

In real world code this kind of optimization is important because it's **extremely** common for people to use things like an `int` loop iteration variable out of habit even though they're actually iterating over a container that can hold `size_t` elements.

Comment: Why _undeflow_? You refer to the fact that it could loop back to the max negative `int`?

Comment: *"`because it's extremely common for people to use things like an int loop iteration variable out of habit even though they're actually iterating over a container that can hold size_t elements.`"* common lack of knowledge is not an excuse.

Comment: @0___________: In many such cases, the "bad habit" would be the use of size_t for the size.  If a function is designed to work with data sets in e.g. the 100-100,000 element range, and and isn't designed to perform well with millions of elements, using `int` as a size would be perfectly reasonable.  The fact that it may be possible to define types whose size exceeds `UINT_MAX` doesn't imply that all functions should be written to work with such monsters.

Comment: //However, since underflow is UB this means that the compiler can assume this won't happen, and it is permitted to make the simplification we made above.// The Standard makes no effort to mandate that compilers behave in ways that are maximally useful to their customers, since the Committee recognized that people seeking to sell compilers would be compelled to do so by the marketplace, with or without a mandate from the Standard.  If nothing a program might do in response to malicious inputs would be unacceptable, the assumptions made by clang and gcc may be reasonable.  Otherwise not.